# Kotlin groupby value as set instead of list

Tags: kotlin

I'm going to groupby `Set<Pair<String,Int>>` values to `Map<String, Set<Int>>` so simply. Find all matching ints for string and create set. I've got solution that works:

```
setStringInt.stream()
            .collect(
                groupingBy(
                    Projection::stringObj,
                    mapping(Projection::intObj,
                        toSet<Int>())
                )
            )
```

I've got kind of cleaner:

```
            .groupBy { it.stringobj }
            .mapValues { it.value.map { it.intobj }.toSet() }
```

But it's looking quite dirty. Do you have any idea how to simplify this? Am I able to do this without using stream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use the Kotlin functions `groupBy` and then `mapValues` directly on the `Set`.

You first use `groupBy` on `it.first` to get a `Map<String, List<Pair<String, Int>>`. Then you need to map the values of the resulting map, so you get a `List<Int>` from the `List<Pair<String, Int>>`. Like this:

```
setStringInt.groupBy { it.first }
            .mapValues { entry -> entry.value.map { it.second }.toSet() }
```

Comment: that maps to a `List` and not a `Set`?

Comment: OP solution doesn't produce intermediate data structures. Without using kotlins `asSequence().groupingBy().fold` you would have to use java stream to be efficient. If `mapValues` is the best Kotlin can do - is it really better than modern java?

Answer (score 15):

I think this is more readable:

```
setStringInt.groupBy({ it.first }, { it.second }).mapValues { it.value.toSet() }
```

using the

```
inline fun <T, K, V> Iterable<T>.groupBy(
    keySelector: (T) -> K,
    valueTransform: (T) -> V
): Map<K, List<V>>
```

overload.